# In Eclipse/EGit how can I see unpushed commits?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Using Eclipse (EGit) how do I see/review commits that haven't been pushed to origin yet?

This is what the history looks like:

[image: EGit History view]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can see whether you have unpushed commits by the arrow and number in the decoration of the project in the explorer view or the *Git Repositories* view. You can see it here:

[image]

In the picture above, the *http-request* repository has 2 unpushed commits.

To review the changes before pushing, you can look at the *History* view. E.g. when you have unpushed commits on the *master* branch, you will see *origin/master* in the history pointing to the latest commit that is known on the remote repository. On top of that, you will see your local commits and the label for *master*.

Let's look at the screenshot from your question:

[image: EGit History view]

This is how to read the history: Start at the commit labeled `master`, which is the topmost one. Then follow the orange line downwards until you arrive at the next commit, which is the third one labeled `origin/master`. So you locally have one more commit, which is shown in the project decorations as an upwards-pointing arrow with the number 1 besides it.

You may be confused by the second commit in the screenshot, labeled `ORIG_HEAD`. When you look at the lines you will see that it is not included between `master` and `origin/master`, but is parallel to `master`. `ORIG_HEAD` is a backup copy of your HEAD before you did a "dangerous" operation such as reset. You can use it to undo a reset for example.

If you don't want to see `ORIG_HEAD` in the history, open the view menu (that little triangle) and deselect *Show* > *Additional Refs*, [see the manual](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#View_Menu_actions).

Comment: That helps, thanks. Especially the "... on top of that you will see local commits". Still not everything's clear to me as I see two local commits there, but the Package Explorer shows [up arrow] 1, but I'll try to dig deeper.

Comment: A screenshot of your history view would help figuring out where the misunderstanding is.

Comment: Thanks, I included your screenshot in the answer and explained how to read the history.

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Window`->`Show View`->`Other`->`GIT`->`Git Reflog`

There you'll see the commits that both have been pushed and those that aren't pushed, but wont differentiate between them.

Better is to use the Egit equivalent of Gitk:

Right click on the Project choose `Team`->`Show in history`. For each commit you'll se which branches that commit is available on. If it only says `<tree-name>` and not `origin/<tree-name>` it means that it isn't pushed.

Comment: Thanks. I am not fully sure I follow fully. I tried that, but I am a bit puzzled. Actually, in each of the options - how do I tell which commits are not pushed yet?